# How to get rid of the box in the middle of the art board

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[image]There is a little box thing in the middle of an art board on Illustrator CS6. Just wanting to ask how I get rid of it. 
It's been there for a while but it's getting really distracting. 
Can't even remember how it got there in the first place.

Please help. thanks x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that there are two extra artboard in file. Check - Window>Artboard. You can delete extra artboard.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu under **View**, select **Hide Page Tiling**.